# Problems on NSArray's -valueForKey: when its item is NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I have an array which contains items of `NSDictionary`, I want to transform the items to other objects, my first thought is `valueForKey:`, so I add a category method `toMyObject` for `NSDictionary`, and call for:

`[array valueForKey:@"toMyObject"]`

But it doesn't work as expect, it just returns the array of `NSNull`s.

Any ideas to solve this problem if I don't want to enumerate the array?

Comment: Hi Dietrich, `NSArray`'s `valueForKey:` will be called for each item and will return a new array which contains the results of item's `valueForKey:`. You can open your Xcode and try this: 

`NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@”foo”, @”bar”, @”baz”, nil]; NSArray *capitals = [array valueForKey:@”capitalizedString”];`

Comment: and here is the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ

Comment: Hm, looks like I haven't been paying attention to Foundation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to myself. The `valueForKey:` of dictionary overwrite the default behavior, if the dictionary doesn't have the key, it will return nil and not call the accessor method as `NSObject` do, as Apple document says:

> If key does not start with “@”, invokes objectForKey:. If key does
>   start with “@”, strips the “@” and invokes [super valueForKey:] with
>   the rest of the key.

Since `NSDictionary` is a cluster class, it's not recommend to subclass to overwrite the behavior. Instead I use the method swiss like this:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (MyAddition)

static void swizzle(Class c, SEL orig, SEL new)
{
  Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, orig);
  Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, new);
  if(class_addMethod(c, orig, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
    class_replaceMethod(c, new, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
  else
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod);
}

+ (void)initialize
{
  if (self == [NSDictionary class]){
    swizzle([NSDictionary class],
            @selector(valueForKey:),
            @selector(myValueForKey:));
  }
}

- (id)toMyObject
{
  return toMyObject;
}

...

- (id)myValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
  // for collection operators
  if ([key compare:@"@" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] == NSOrderedSame)
    return [super valueForKey:key];

  if ([key isEqualToString:@"toMyObject"])
    return [self toMyObject];

  return [self myValueForKey:key];
}
```

Now it's safe for an NSArray to call `valueForKey:@"toMyObject"`.

Comment: 1. Why do you think swizzling is safer than subclassing on class clusters? (it isn't)

Comment: 2. `myValueForKey:` calls itself recursively forever when key is not "toMyObject".

Comment: 3. It's still not safe to call `valueForKey:` on arrays or dictionaries. Don't do that without making sure that keys are sanitized.

Comment: 4. It's a very obfuscated architecture anyway. What does it buy you to have this overly complicated way of converting an array of dictionaries? Why not just write a method that iterates over the objects and does the conversion?

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe, for syntax sugar.

Comment: Seems more like syntax vinegar to me, though.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe fixed forever recursion

Answer (score 0):

One more implementation without swizzling:

```
@implementation NSObject (MLWValueForKey)

- (id)mlw_valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        return [self valueForKey:key];
    }
    NSAssert(![key containsString:@":"], @"Key should be selector without arguments");
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    return [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}

@end

@implementation NSArray (MLWValueForKey)

- (id)mlw_valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        return [self valueForKey:key];
    }
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (id object in self) {
        [array addObject:[object mlw_valueForKey:key]];
    }
    return array;
}

@end
```